# Where do I fetch myself complete definition for a bundle?

Tags: 8, entities, i18n-l10n

I can fetch entity-type definition...

```
$entityType = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getDefinition($this->entityType);
```

and I can fetch myself *some* of the bundle specific information...

```
if ($bundleName !== null) {
    $bundleConfig = $entityType->getBundleConfigDependency($bundleName);
    $config = HelperConfiguration::instance($bundleConfig["name"]);
    $configValues = $config->getConfigValue();
}
```

$configValues carries properties like description, preview_mode, display_submitted, even langcode, but what I cannot find, is how to find translatability status for a bundle.

On `/admin/config/regional/content-language` I can wonderfully manipulate translatability bulk-wise, from entity-coarseness, up to specific fields.

So, while there is an isTranslatable() method on `EntityTypeInterface` (and also on`FieldDefinitionInterface`), where is the bundle equivalent? Where is the rest of bundle's metadata hidden?

Comment: When I have entity, I can check upon `$entity instanceof TranslatableInterface`, right? So that could be used as a hack... just instantiate quickly one and test it....naah.

Comment: No, this wouldn't tell you whether the bundle is translatable, this information is stored in configuration. See the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the language specific configuration of a bundle use [ContentLanguageSettings::loadByEntityTypeBundle](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21language%21src%21Entity%21ContentLanguageSettings.php/function/ContentLanguageSettings%3A%3AloadByEntityTypeBundle/8.9.x).

For the translatability of the bundle, you'd use:

```
$settings = ContentLanguageSettings::loadByEntityTypeBundle($entity_type_id, $bundle_name);
$isBundleTranslatable = $settings->getThirdPartySetting("content_translation", "enabled");
```

You could also use [ContentTranslationManager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21content_translation%21src%21ContentTranslationManager.php/class/ContentTranslationManager/8.9.x):

```
/** @var ContentTranslationManager $contentTranslationManager */
$contentTranslationManager = \Drupal::service('content_translation.manager');
$isBundleTranslatable = $contentTranslationManager->isEnabled($entity_type_id, $bundle_name);
```

Comment: Huge thank you for your ever swift answers. But where do I go on from there? Does `status()` provide the translatability flag?

Comment: It's stored in the third party settings of that config, see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21content_translation%21src%21ContentTranslationManager.php/function/ContentTranslationManager%3A%3AisEnabled/8.9.x