# How to check if a Vocabulary is translatable?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

In Drupal Core, I found the following code:

```
$entity instanceof TranslatableDataInterface && $entity->isTranslatable()
```

But it looks like it is not working for the Taxonomy vocabularies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is stored in configuration and you can retrieve it by using this service:

```
\Drupal::service('content_translation.manager')->isEnabled('taxonomy_term', 'my_vocab')
```

More info [Where do I fetch myself complete definition for a bundle?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/292573/where-do-i-fetch-myself-complete-definition-for-a-bundle)

Comment: Many thanks for this nice code.

Answer (score 0):

`$entity instanceof TranslatableDataInterface && $entity->isTranslatable()` doesn't work because the first part is checking for the wrong interface. The correct code is the following one.

```
$entity instanceof TranslatableInterface && $entity->isTranslatable()
```

It's [`TranslatableInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TypedData%21TranslatableInterface.php/8.9.x) that defines `isTranslatable()`. [`TranslatableDataInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/8.9.x/search/TranslatableDataInterface) is not an interface defined from Drupal core.

The documentation page for the [`Term`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21Entity%21Term.php/class/Term/8.9.x) class has a list of its methods. You can also see which class implements them, and which method they override. In the case of `isTranslatable()` the page reports the following data.

```
ContentEntityBase::isTranslatable    public    function    Returns the translation support status.
                                                           Overrides TranslatableInterface::isTranslatable
```

The [`Vocabulary`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21Entity%21Vocabulary.php/class/Vocabulary/8.9.x) class, which is the class for the configuration entity used to define the bundles of the *Taxonomy term* entity (a content entity), doesn't have any `isTranslatable()` method.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information however, I will accept the 4k4 answer as it is solving my issue: How to know if a vocabulary is translatable.